# How to make common properties from class as generic

Tags: ios, swift, generics

For example I have 4 model classes which contains 3 properties named name, value and amounts. How to make a generic class that accept my model class and works accordingly. Each class has the objects of another class. Resulting in tree like structure

```
Class A  {
//Its own properties
var name:String?
var value:Int?
var amounts:[Double?]
var listOfB:B?
}

Class B {
//Its own properties
var name:String?
var value:Int?
var amounts:[Double?]
var listOfC:C?
}

Class C {
//Its own properties
var name:String?
var value:Int?
var amounts:[Double?]
var listOfD:D?
}

Class D {
//Its own properties
var name:String?
var value:Int?
var amounts:[Double?]
}
```

Code so far

```
public class BaseModel<T: BaseModel> {
    public var avg : Double?
    public var id : String!
    public var subModels :[T]

    init(model: [T]) {
    }
}

class GenericModel<T: BaseModel > { // Model for all subclasses

 init(model: T) {
    if let a = model as? ListOfYears {
        model.avg = self.avg
        model.id = self.id
        model.subModel .init(model:self.subModels)
    }
    if let a = model as? listOfMonths {
        model.avg = self.avg
        model.id = self.id
        model.subModels.init(model:self.subModels)
    }
    if let a = model as? ListOfWeeks {
        model.avg = self.avg
        model.id = self.id
        model.subModels .init(model:ListOfYears.listOfMonths)
    }
}
```

Here ListOfYears, ListOfMonths, ListOfWeeks are my model classes

Comment: You need `superclass` here, there's **nothing** `generic` here.

Comment: `listOfT: T? // T in [B, C, D]` — that's not a list, that's optional value

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to force something to be generic when it really doesn't need to be. As @user28434 quite rightly pointed out, a good old fashioned superclass will do nicely here. Here is an example for your case:

```
class BaseModel {
    var name:String?
    var value:Int?
    var amounts:[Double]?
}

class A: BaseModel  {
    //Its own properties
}

class B: BaseModel {
    //Its own properties
}

class C: BaseModel {
    //Its own properties
}

class D: BaseModel {
    //Its own properties
}
```

Comment: In my case each class should contain its own variables means different name, value amounts. And Class A contains array of class B likewise. A, B, C, D acts just like year month week days

Comment: In your example property of class A will override which of Base Model

Comment: Please clarify you questions. Perhaps you need `class GenericModel<T: BaseModel >` and `init(model: T) {  if( let a = model as? A) { ..} }`

Comment: @Saranjith, `each class should contain its own variables means different name` — variables with same name can contain different values, `And Class A contains array of class B likewise. ` — that's what you put instead of `//Its own properties` comment.

Comment: yes. I have done something like that please see my edit